# DIV moves when zoom-in in browse (foundation framework)

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

My div is moving around when the zooming in,and it goes below the navigation

picture of the problem 
http://store2.up-00.com/2016-08/1470571909991.png

I tried to set  min-width but it didn't work!.

note that I'm using foundation framework for CSS!
HTML -

```
<?php include 'core/init.php';?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Social Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home_style.css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="large-8 columns">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Members</li>
                    <li>Topics:</li>
                    <?php   $get_topics = "SELECT *  FROM `topics`";
                            $run_topic =  mysqli_query($con, $get_topics);
                            while ($topics = mysqli_fetch_array($run_topic)){
                                    $topic_id = $topics['topic_title'];
                                    $topic_title = $topics['topic_title'];
                                echo "<li><a href='home.php?topic=$topic_id'>$topic_title </a></li>";
                            }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="large-4 columns  right" >
                <form action="" method="post" class="search">
                    <label>Search</label>
                    <input type="text" name="search" class="search_input">
                    <input type="submit" name="search_b" value="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1300px;
    background: #eee; /* Fills the page */
    position: relative; /* Fix for absolute positioning */
}

header  {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #5f5f5f;
    font-weight: bold;

}

header ul.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;
    line-height: 60px;
}


.search {
    margin-top: 12px;
}
.search_input {
    display: inline;
}
.search input[type=text] {
    width: 200px;
}

.search label {
    display: inline;
}




/*REMOVE FOUNDATION STYLE*/
.menu > li > a {
    padding: 0;
}



html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,   blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch your `header` style... `height: 70px;` is your problem. Your browser tries to move the element under others, but it has set height, so your element floats in nothing. Try to remove this attribute.

Comment: Thank you. after I removed the height it goes under the  ul li menu http://store1.up-00.com/2016-08/1470572498261.png, but I want it to  be fixed and not move around when I zoom in. I used min-width to achieve that but it didn't work as I said before.

Comment: @AhmadzIssa Well, even you zoom in, your elements will get bigger, so one of them will always get under others. What do you want to get? If you Set width of container with all links, you will still see some elements floating under others when zooming in..

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I just added " medium-8 small-8" to the div after I read " it will get bigger" and it works fine now .Thanks.